# Run BAT file as a Local User Account

Tags: powershell

I pulled this from another question, but I cannot seem to make this work.

I need to run this .bat file as a local admin account.  I want users to be able to run and install this without having local admin rights.

I'm not sure what's wrong though.

```
$username = 'localadmin'
$password = 'passwordforlocaladmin'
$securePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $password -AsPlainText -Force
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential $username, $securePassword
Start-Process -Filepath "p:\kaceInstaller\kaceinstall3.bat" -Credential $credential
```

The error I'm getting back is:

```
Start-Process : This command cannot be executed due to the error: The directory
name is invalid.
At P:\kaceInstaller\misc\kaceSetup.ps1:7 char:14
+ Start-Process <<<<  cmd -Credential $credential
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Start-Process], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperationException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartProcessCommandy
```

Comment: I am assuming that the P drive is a network drive? If so you may need to put a line in there regarding net use P: <path to share> I think the equivalent of this cmd in                                              PS is New-PSDrive –Name “P” –PSProvider FileSystem –Root “\\touchsmart\share” –Persist

Comment: Thanks--the network drive is already mapped by group policy to _P:_.  It's also calling the .bat file from the same working directory.

Comment: The error makes me think it doesnt like something about that path, if you run it from C does it behave the same?

Comment: If Start-Process used with credentials is anything like running a shortcut with right click Run As Administrator then I THINK everything is run in the context of the hidden local admin account, which doesn't have the drive letter mapped. If you use a UNC path does it work?

Comment: @superKing, yep, the problem is with the network drive. It's mapped for the logged in user all right, but you are trying to start the process under a different user, who is not logged on, and thus for that use the drive is not mapped. I've seen this many times but I'm not aware of a work-around.

Comment: Also note that you are effectively giving your users localadmin name and password, since they need to be able to read your .ps1 script in order to run it.

Comment: If a UNC path works, you can extract the UNC path from the mapped drive letter then use it to run the BAT. Just in case different UNC paths but consistent drive letters might be the condition you have.

Comment: I would suggest running this remotely using a wmi `Win32_Process`, `psexec` or something similar so you don't give the users the local admin password. + use UNC-path

Comment: I thought that UNC paths didn't work in Powershell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to allow users to run something as a local administrator account without effectively giving them the password to the local admin account, I would suggest to create a scheduled task running as a local admin. Users can manually trigger that task, which will then be executed under the local admin account. Creating the task withoug saving the credentials should work, but even if you have to save the credentials they won't be accessible to your users.

For access to network shares you may need to connect/disconnect the share with explicit credentials from within the script that the scheduled task runs, though, because the local account usually doesn't have permission to access the network drives mapped by your domain user.

```
net use X: \\server\share\kaceInstaller password /user:DOMAIN\user
call X:\kaceinstall3.bat
net use X: /d
```

Make `DOMAIN\user` a dedicated account that has access only to `\\server\share` and nothing else to minimize risk.

Note that you **must** make sure that the script run by the task is not writable by regular users, otherwise they will be able to run arbitrary commands with admin privileges by simply modifying the script.